# Numerical Methods for Maximizing a Matrix Function

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I am looking for references which present numerical methods for maximizing real-valued functions taking as argument a matrix. I haven't been able to find any approaches for this problem, except perhaps Gradient Ascent. I am unsure whether the latter is appropriate for my problem, and would like to compare it with other existing methods.

In my specific case, the function which I wish to maximize is a variation of the function $Q$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Gaussian_mixture), with all variables assumed to be known and fixed except the matrices $\Sigma_j$ (a closed-form solution does not exist in my case). In particular, the $\Sigma_j$ are constrained to be symmetric and positive definite, which further increases the difficulty of the problem.

Does anyone have suggestions for references which may address this type of problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not really any different than maximising a vector taking functions.

Comment: Could you please provide an example, or a reference in which this is treated?

Comment: If the input is positive definite, you probably entered the domain of semi-definite programming, i.e., there are infinitely many linear constraints on the input of the form $v^TXv\ge0$ for all $\|v\|=1$.

Comment: This is great, I had never heard of semi-definite programming before. If you could elaborate below, I would gladly mark your answer as best.

Comment: A genetic algorithm does precisely this. You give it a vector of initial inputs, allow it to traverse some sort of solution space and it should converge to maximise or minimise your function.